# Textures messed up when animating character

Tags: animation, texturing

after rerigging my character with a mixamo animation the clothes of my character shows some stribes / spots that shouldn`t be there. I attached a photo of the character. Maybe somebody has an idea how to fix this problem?

Thanx Alex!

[image: picture]
[image: shading]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So in tpose the clothes of the character look right. As soon as I move the bones in specific direction the clothes mesh get moved / strechted so that the word mashine f.e. that is written on the pants is disorted. I will also try to attach a screenshot of the shading elements of the pants.

Comment: Put a texture Texture Coordinate Node with it's UV output plugged into a texture Mapping node, and then plug that into the Vector input of every texture in your your material. See if that works.

Comment: The Textrure Cordinate Node in combination with the texture Mapping didn`t solve it so far but the vendor also gave me the following information: "that would be a skinning issue...
mixamo autorig and also auto skin your character, and sometimes it does it well while other times it fails.
it will mostly fail with complex characters, so u may need to modify the skinning manually.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WqGmxioSdE
"
So it may be a skinning issue. I will check the youtube link he provided me and try my best. Hope this helps others who may have the same problem too

Comment: Not the best way but I think I solved it somehow. The disrupted text ist gone because I deleted this part in the textures. So no text anymore on the pants that is getting disrupted. The other problem was the skin that was shining through the clothes at some points when animating the character. So I deleted the skin in this area. My character is now without legs but when he is not naked no one will see :D